# Time Complexity of ELT Function in Common Lisp for Various Sequence Types

Tags: time-complexity, common-lisp, sequence, element

I am trying to get an understanding of how the `ELT` function works when it comes to different sequence types.

It seems obvious that when a list is passed to it, then the performance is of order `O(n)`. 
Is it true to say that getting an element from a `VECTORP` sequence is of order `O(1)`?
What about a string?

This does not seem to be specified on [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_elt.htm) or Common Lisp The Language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, the ANSI CL standard does not specify implementation
details - including performance issues such as this one. Another example
is tail call elimination, mandated by Scheme but not CL.
This does not mean, of course, that the authors of the standard were
oblivious to performance (cf. "performance impact" section in every
[issue](http://clhs.lisp.se/Issues/I_Alpha.htm) writeup).

That said, you can safely assume that [`elt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm) is `O(1)` on
[`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm)s (including [string](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_string.htm)s).

I don't think [`elt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm) is used very often though - mostly because one
usually knows whether a [`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm) or a [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm) is actually used.
Using
[`aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_aref.htm)/[`char`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm)/[`nth`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm)
serves as extra code documentation.

PS. The rationale for this dramatic difference between CL and Scheme is that Scheme's origin is in *teaching*: its users are new students who should learn computer programming as a methodology of expressing ideas about algorithms, thus they should have a relatively simple tool with clearly defined behavior.
ANSI CL's [history](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/01_ab.htm) shows that the standard was a result of an effort of several existing vendors to come up with some common ground for better portability - to make competition more fair, so to speak. The audience are seasoned programmers who know the trade and can understand performance trade offs.

Comment: Do you mean I can make a CL that is fully compliment and that stores arrays and strings as lists?

Comment: @Sylwester: yes, absolutely. No one will use it thought ;-)